# How to handle more application states of the same user with Vaadin 6

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin6

I have problem with stepping forward with our Vaadin 6 application.
Do you know any way to properly handle more states of the application for the same user?

I mean for example we share URLs on social sites and those urls identify sort of states and user can visit these URLs but our problem when you open one state in one window and another state (another url) in other window, Vaadin6 will drop the firstly opened state because it stores them in the same session.

I've already found that Vaadin 7 could handle this in better way but we are in the middle of decision making how to go forward so I'm planning to measure all the possibilities with all the costs.

- migrating from 6 to 7
- tricking around with session management
- ... etc

I'd very appreciate if you could recommend some good way to deal with this issue.

Thank you, in advance, for all of your ideas.

Comment: I think for Vaadin6 there is a way to handle this via unique/different window names. (You might search in the vaadin forum for more details). But the move to vaadin7 might anyway be on your roadmap, so why not priorize it?

Comment: @AndréSchild, good idea, thank you, I gave you an upvote :)
Yes, migration is on its way, we just wanted to know if we'd need more resources to be on time or there is a quick fix and migration can go on as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have same issue and resolve with help http://tobias-mattsson-magnolia.blogspot.ru/2012/05/vaadin-applications-and-tabbed-browsing.html

Full source code you can found here: http://pastie.org/3962656

Comment: thanks for the answer, I also found this, after @AndréSchild suggestion and when I'll have time to test it I'm going to accept your answer.
(I've already hit the upvote button :) )